# Prove that the tangent planes at a point of a smooth surface are the same

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $z=f(x,y)$, $y=g(x,z)$, and $x=h(y,z)$ be continously differentiable functions that can be derived from an implicit function $F(x,y,z)=0$. Each of these functions define a surface and, at a point $\mathbf a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, the corresponding tangent planes to these surfaces can be found as follows:

$$z-a_3=[Df(a_1,a_2)]\begin{bmatrix} x-a_1 \\ y-a_2\end{bmatrix} \\ y-a_2=[Dg(a_1,a_3)]\begin{bmatrix} x-a_1 \\ z-a_3\end{bmatrix} \\x-a_1=[Dh(a_2,a_3)]\begin{bmatrix} y-a_2 \\ z-a_3\end{bmatrix}$$

Following [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1466913/137035), we can express these tangent planes in the $\vec n \cdot \vec x=\vec n \cdot \vec p$ form as below:

$$\begin{bmatrix} D_1f(a_1,a_2) \\ D_2f(a_1,a_2) \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} D_1f(a_1,a_2) \\ D_2f(a_1,a_2) \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} D_1g(a_1,a_3) \\ -1\\D_3g(a_1,a_3) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} D_1g(a_1,a_3) \\ -1\\D_3g(a_1,a_3) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ D_2h(a_2,a_3) \\ D_3h(a_2,a_3) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ D_2h(a_2,a_3) \\ D_3h(a_2,a_3) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $D_n$ denotes the $n$th directional derivative. How can I show that above equations actually define the same plane?

**EDIT**:

If first and second planes are the same, then there is the following relation between them (as Thomas stated):

$$\begin{bmatrix} D_1f(a_1,a_2) \\ D_2f(a_1,a_2) \\ -1 \end{bmatrix}=k\begin{bmatrix} D_1g(a_1,a_3) \\ -1\\D_3g(a_1,a_3) \end{bmatrix}$$

We can find a relation between them using implicit function theorem. According to this theorem, if $F(x,y,f(x,y))=0$, then $Df(a_1,a_2)=-[D_1F(\mathbf a) \; D_2F(\mathbf a)]^{-1}[D_3F(\mathbf a)]$. Thus, $D_1f(a_1,a_2)=-[D_1F(\mathbf a) \; D_2F(\mathbf a)]^{-1}[D_3F(\mathbf a)]\vec e_1$ where $\vec e_1$ is the direction towards $x$.  I don't know how to construct other relations using implicit function theorem. I know these notations are odd but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The normal to a tangent plane is, up to sign, unique, if you are working in a codimension $1$ case. So if you can show that the planes have the same normal or the normal differs only by a nonzero (positive or negative) factor, then the planes coincide. If two normal vectors are linearly independent (as in your example) the planes do not coincide.